# How to save Structure Variable Values to .csv file in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I am trying to save a structure value into a .csv file.  The structure variable values are (x,y) co-ordinates values of two straight lines.

[I tried to save the structure using these code lines, the structure has another structre inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uLSF.jpg)

After saving I tried to open the saved file through excel but I got strange characters in excel.[Here is how I got the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMbuR.jpg)

Is there anyone who can help me on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the save() function saves it to a matlab specific file format.

Try csvwrite('points.csv', s);

here's a link to the [Matlab Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)

Comment: It didn't work, showing error.  the example in the link was given for matrix, in my case it is structure.